# Can I use a d3 transition to stagger execution of an arbitrary function, and if so, how?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have an update() function of some complexity which is executed on each element of a large array named tool_animations.

Rather than transitions within this function, I'd like to stagger execution of the function itself:

```
playback_transition = d3.transition()
.delay(function(){ return (elem_dur_in_ms * curr_index); })
.duration(0);

d3.selectAll(tool_animations)
    .each(function() {
        this.update();
});
```

Though a misuse of transitions, I initially thought I might get something like the following to work. (It's now clear this is only passing the transition's parameters down into the update() call).

```
d3.selectAll(tool_animations)
    .each(function() {
        var curr_arr_elem = this;
        playback_transition.call(curr_arr_elem.update);
});
```

Any idea how I might stagger the update call itself? Grateful for any suggestions, preferably d3-based, no jQuery. Thanks :-)

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can add an [end event listener](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) to the transition that you stagger and call the function you want to call in the handler.

Comment: Spot on, simple change, worked instantly:
'playback_transition.each("end", function(){       curr_array_elem.update();
});'

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 allows you to add [event listeners](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) to the transition. That is, you can have a function called when the transition starts or when it ends. In your case, you can use the "end" listener to stagger the calls. Simply initialise the transitions with delay as before and add the following code:

```
.each("end", functionToCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with setTimeout:

```
d3.selectAll(tool_animations)

    .each( function(d,i) {
        var curr_arr_elem = this;
        setTimeout( function () {
            playback_transition.call(curr_arr_elem.update);
        }, i * 100 );
    });
```